# Finding derivative of $f(u(x))$ with respect to $f(x)$, where $x=e(u(x))$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Applying the chain rule and the fact that $u(x)=ln(x)$,

$f'(u(x))u'(x) = f'(u(x))/x$, but I do not know what that is in terms of $f'(x)$.

Comment: A tree diagram can be helpful to digout the derivative